# Can't get the duplication check working with ajax in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to call a method with ***ajax*** which checks for ***duplicate email***. Below is my code

```
#users_controller.rb
def check_email
  email = User.find_by(email: params[:email]) #record exists

  if email
    #return true
    render :json => { status: "true" }
  else
    return false
  end
end

#view code

<input type="email" name="email" id="s_email"  placeholder="Email"/>
<span id="duplicate_email"></span>

#jquery
$('#s_email').on('change keyup paste', function() {

  var email = $('#s_email').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/users/check_email',
    data: {"email": email},
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(status){
      if (status == 'true') {
        $('#duplicate_email').text("Email Already Exists! Try Different Email");
      }
    }
  });
});

#server log
Started GET "/users/check_email?email=pavan%40xyz.in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-28 11:45:02 +0530
Processing by UsersController#check_email as JSON
  Parameters: {"email"=>"pavan@xyz.in"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :login_check rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 0ms
```

***Problem:***
Though the record exists, the error never shows up.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Filter chain halted as :login_check rendered or redirected` do you see that error? Also `staus == 'true'` should be `staus.status == 'true'`

Comment: I think the problem is in `success: function(staus){`, **status** refers to whole data returned by rails i.e `{ status: "true" }` so in your code `if (staus == 'true') {` evaluates to false. what you need is `if (staus.status == 'true') {` or rename `function(staus)` to `function(data)` and use as `data.status`

Comment: @Зелёный Nice pointer! I was sort of mistaken that error. You are right. I have to add `skip_before_filter :login_check` to that controller and also need to change `status == 'true'` to `status.status == 'true'`. Now working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the error `Filter chain halted as :login_check rendered or redirected` looks like an authentication error. Also `staus == 'true'` should be `staus.status == 'true'` according to your action code.